# Use nginx as proxy with docker

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, docker, proxy

I currently try to use nginx as a proxy for elasticsearch engine, all with docker.
My run command for elasticsearch is the following :

```
docker run --name elasticsearch_5.2.1 \
-d \
elasticsearch:5.2.1
```

The one for nginx :

```
docker run --name nginx_1.11.10 \
-p 8200:80 \
-l elasticsearch_5.2.1:elasticsearch \
-v /my.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
-d \
nginx:1.11.10
```

And my nginx config is :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    upstream elasticsearch_proxy {
        server elasticsearch:9200;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://elasticsearch_proxy;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
            proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
        }
    }
}
```

But, when nginx start, I have this error :

```
2017/03/01 23:45:47 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "elasticsearch:9200" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "elasticsearch:9200" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15
```

I understand that nginx can't found elasticsearch with his alias. But I can't find the problem.

Is there someone who already has this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a user network.

```
docker create network my_app
```

And then run both containers on that network.

```
docker run --name elasticsearch_5.2.1 \
-d --network my_app \
elasticsearch:5.2.1

docker run --name nginx_1.11.10 \
-p 8200:80 \
-l elasticsearch_5.2.1:elasticsearch \
--network my_app \
-v /my.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
-d \
nginx:1.11.10
```

Then you should be able to resolve names properly as if they were DNS names.

Comment: `docker-compose` makes this easy as well.

Comment: @OresteViron What if you tell nginx.conf to use the hostname `elasticsearch_5.2.1` ? Or `--name elasticsearch` on the first container?

Comment: @OresteViron It's because the "link" option is deprecated and I don't think the automatic "DNS-like" names are working like they used to anymore. The "correct" way now is to use Docker user networks.